# Cannot POST /file.php

Tags: php, session

I'm having a problem with **php**, the problem is I only get **Cannot POST /file.php** error 
after I click submit button. I'm using LAMPP and activate the *webserver service*, and I've place my project into /htdocs folder, but its still the same.

this is my code:
html

```
<form id="flogin" method="post" action="phpe.php"> <!--form login-->
<input id="user" name="user" placeholder="username" type="text">
<input id="pass" name="pass" placeholder="password" type="password"><br>
<input id="bf" type="submit" value="login">
</form>
```

phpe.php:

```
<?php
$username="singduwe";
$password="websiteiki";

if($_POST["user"]==$username and $_POST["pass"]==$password){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["admin"]="yes";
    header("location:admin.php");
}else{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["admin"]="no";
    header("location:index.html");
}

?>
```

admin.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

?>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    hi</body>
</html>
```

**update**
I'm using Brackets code editor

Comment: yes, because I don't know much about php, Im a noob,

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 right, your code is fine. i already tried that code... maybe you can follow veeru answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gave your code a quick try and it works as expected. May be you are  missing something in your setup? what is exact error message?

It looks to me like your webserver does not have PHP installed?

How did you install your LAMP stack? Since you said LAMP, i am assuming your server is linux.

Please check if php is installed on your server, if it is, is Apache configured to use PHP?

It is rather easy to install using yum or apt-get, based on your linux installation. Take a look at this
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu

To do a quick check if php is installed, create a test file with

```
<?PHP 
 phpinfo();
?>
```

If everything is well, you should see a bunch of PHP information...something like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qBq6.png

Your code is pretty straight forward and should not fail unless your setup is wrong. If you are windows user, try a locally hosted WAMP server; that will be helpful if you do not wish to fiddle with Linux.

Comment: I' install XAMPP for linux, and it is a bundle of package include PHP, are LAMP is thesame as XAMPP? here the site [https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html]

Comment: I always used xampp/wamp on windows, never really tried it on linux. But that's how it should work, everything in one package. Install, start it and code.

Comment: maybe you should try reinstall your lampp.

Comment: my php is fine, I've create php file with _phpinfo()_ in it, and running it on browser, and it show the long detail info,

Comment: We are pointing towards an error in your PHP because, the code you posted works without an issue.
http://i.imgur.com/0TqYRpN.png
http://i.imgur.com/JywmPd4.png
May be you can host your files somewhere and take help from one of the members here. It could even be some sort of encoding issue?

Comment: thank you, but it works now :D the problem is file permissions on my project folder in htdocs, after I change the permissions, its work,:)

Comment: That is a valid reason. But the message was misleading. Glad u solved it. Make sure u mark some ones response as answer

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to edit `action="phpe.php"` to `action="yourdirectory/phpe.php"`

It may work. If it'll still same, please give me more details.

Comment: yes, its still the same, I've change _header("location:/jumat/phpe.php")_ and _action="/jumat/phpe.php"_

Comment: if phpe.php path is " / ", just update action value with /phpe.php, please give us error message.

Comment: can you send me the print?

Comment: @yuda the error is the same as the title, I've change it,

Comment: @birlikbilisim do you mean the screenshot?

Comment: No but screenshot is OK too.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure your php file path is included in the portion of the code you are calling it. Sound like the project is not stored in the default htdocs folder.
Cheers